# Create an appointment with required attendees in Lotus Notes using VBA in Access 2013

Tags: vba, calendar, lotus-notes, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to create a check out log for inventory in Access 2013. During this process you will create an appointment on the expected return date in the Lotus Notes 9 calendar. I have found enough examples to do this successfully. However I am getting stuck when trying to add people to the "RequiredAttendees" field. I am pretty sure that I am using the right field name but i keep getting the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)':  Automation error.  The server
>   threw an exception.

Everything else works fine except the part that tries to add attendees. I know Lotus Notes 9 is old and I know Access 2013 is old but those are the tools I am required to work with. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Function test() As Variant

Dim StartTime As Date
Dim MailDbName As String
Dim CalenDoc As Object
Dim WorkSpace As Object
Dim AppDate As String
Dim AppTime As String
Dim Subject As String

Set WorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NOTESUIWORKSPACE")

AppDate = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the return date:")
'Subject = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the subject:")
'AppTime = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the time:")

MailDbName = "mail\User.nsf"

strSTime = CStr(Timex)

Set CalenDoc = WorkSpace.COMPOSEDOCUMENT("MailServer", MailDbName, "Appointment")
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "AppointmentType", "3"
CalenDoc.Refresh

CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "StartDate", CStr(AppDate)
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "EndDate", CStr(AppDate)
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "StartTime", "12:00 PM"
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "EndTime", "12:00 PM"
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "Subject", "Test"

GetUser = Environ("UserName")
EmailAddress = GetUser & "@company.com"

If EmailAddress = "User1@company.com" Then
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "RequiredAttendees", "User2@company.com" & "," & "User3@company.com"
CalenDoc.Refresh
ElseIf EmailAddress = "User2@company.com" Then
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "RequiredAttendees", "User1@company.com" & "," & "User3@company.com"
CalenDoc.Refresh
ElseIf EmailAddress = "User3@company.com" Then
CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "RequiredAttendees", "User2@company.com" & "," & "User1@company.com"
CalenDoc.Refresh
Else
MsgBox (EmailAddress & "is not a valid email address.")
End If


'CalenDoc.gotoField "Body"
'CalenDoc.InsertText Body
CalenDoc.Refresh
'CalenDoc.Save
'CalenDoc.Close
'Set CalenDoc = Nothing
'Set WorkSpace = Nothing
```

Comment: On which line are you receiving the error?

Comment: @dwirony At the very first CalenDoc.FIELDSETTEXT "RequiredAttendees"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've been confused by looking at examples that use the back-end COM classes instead of, or maybe in addition to, examples that use the front-end OLE classes. You are using Notes.NOTESUIWORKSPACE - OLE, instead of Lotus.NotesSession - COM. That means you have to use the actual editable fields on the Appointment form, which are sometimes not what you expect them to be. In some cases, these front-end fields are not the same as the items that will end up being stored in the back-end document - and it's the back-end item names that are typically documented because they are the ones that get stored in the note.

RequiredAttendees is the stored item name, but you are getting the automation error because it's a computed field on the Appointment form, not an editable field.

Since you are using OLE, you need to enter the data into the "EnterSendTo" field. The data that you (or a user) puts in there will, in fact, end up in the RequiredAttendees item due to the magic that goes on in the formulas and scripts associated with the Appointment form.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what I needed. I am new to working with Notes and did not realize there was a difference.